# Change The Value of a Field in a Multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this

```
Array
(  
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => The Title
            [Price] => 700
            [Quantity] => 2
        )

)
```

Say I wanted to change the Quantity to 5 how would I do that if the array were stored in the variable $ItemArray?

Comment: You have an associative array nested in a numeric one:  `$itemArray[0]['Quantity'] = 5;` See [the PHP arrays manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for all the details & examples.

Comment: Why the hate guys?  It's a clear, simple question.  No need to downvote a fellow coder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$itemArray[0]['Quantity'] = 5;`.

Basically, you have an array, `$itemArray`, which contains an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). To access that inside array, you simply use standard PHP array syntax: `$itemArray[0]`.

Then, you need the `Quantity` field of that inner array. Using the nested array syntax, you append `['Quantity']` to the end of our previous statement, resulting in: `$itemArray[0]['Quantity']`.

At this point, you have the field you want, and you can use the normal `=` to set the field value.

```
$itemArray[0]['Quantity'] = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

thats very simple, try

```
$itemArray[0]["Quantity"] = 5;
```

What we're doing here is accessing the first index within $itemArray which is 0; 0 contains an array, so we now specify which part of 0 we want to access: Like this basically:

```
$array[index][innerarrayindex]
```